Won't stop showing desktop on the bottom left corner even though Hot Corners are disabled
The bottom left corner pulls all the windows out of the way to show the desktop, which is a feature I'd like to disable.
In the same manner, the top right corner always highlights the current program (or all of its types running, like multiple Chrome instances).
What do I do to make it stop? (I set the options menu in hopes it would replace the go-to-desktop functionality but it doesn't do anything.)
I was hoping Hot Corners in System Preferences would be of some use to disable too but to no avail.


There are multiple Hot Corners controls in System Preferences.
For example, if you look for "hot corners" with Spotlight (press Commandspace, type "hot corners" and press Enter) you get something totally different than what you get in Desktop & Dock.
The result you get from Spotlight is the setting for the Accessibility Keyboard (its exact location is System Preferences > Accessibility > Keyboard > Accessibility Keyboard).

Please accept the answer to show that the question has been resolved.
